# Performing click on a button of a child in recycler view using espresso

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

Within an activity, I have a custom recycler view that contains 2 textviews and 2 buttons as shown below.

[image]

The id for the recycling bin icon button is deleteButton. I would like to access this button within espresso testing so that I can mock a click.

Two methods that I have attempted and failed are shown below:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.basket))
                .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(4, click() ));

        onView(withText("Cherry"))
                .perform(
                        RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(
                                hasDescendant(withId(R.id.deleteButton)),
                                ViewActions.click()
                        )
                );
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to click on a view inside a `RecyclerView` item view is by creating a custom view action:

```
public static ViewAction actionOnItemView(Matcher<View> matcher, ViewAction action) {

    return new ViewAction() {

        @Override public String getDescription() {
            return String.format("performing ViewAction: %s on item matching: %s", action.getDescription(), StringDescription.asString(matcher));
        }

        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(withParent(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class)), isDisplayed());
        }

        @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            List<View> results = new ArrayList<>();
            for (View v : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                if (matcher.matches(v)) results.add(v);
            }
            if (results.isEmpty()) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No view found %s", StringDescription.asString(matcher)));
            } else if (results.size() > 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Ambiguous views found %s", StringDescription.asString(matcher)));
            }
            action.perform(uiController, results.get(0));
        }
    };
}
```

Then use one of the [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions) on your `RecyclerView`, then `actionOnItemView` as subsequent action on the item view if successful:

```
ViewAction itemViewAction = actionOnItemView(withId(R.id.deleteButton), click());
onView(withId(your_recycler_view)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(4, itemViewAction));
```